# Implement website payment solution

Tags: payment

I want to implement a bitcoin paying system to my website. I came up with this http://bitfreak.info/?page=tools&t=bitsci but I am unable to understand how it's working.

I looked up into the sourcecode but I don't get where I can get the bitcoins after the user has paid. The term WIF is used a lot; what is that?

Is there any simpler solution? I don't want to use a third-party service

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create your own implementation using the Bitcoin Client, you ought to look into [Accounts](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Accounts_explained). This concept would allow you to have complete control over your users' payments, but it would also mean that you have to implement your own solution that would be communicating with Bitcoind.

There is also a more complete [solution from StrongCoin](https://www.strongcoin.com/blog/bitcoin_micropayments_with_strongcoin) in PHP, but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

The MultiBit Merchant project provides a demonstration of how to use the [BitCoinJ](http://code.google.com/p/bitcoinj/) library to accept payments using Java. At the time of writing, the source code can be found here: https://github.com/gary-rowe/MultiBitMerchant

If you want more detail about how to get started let me know.

Answer (score 0):

WIF stands for [Wallet Import Format](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Wallet_import_format), which is a string of text that can be converted to a private key. [More info here too](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/1720/516).

You should be able to [import the private key into your Bitcoin client](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/3532/516), though I'm not 100% sure whether it accepts WIF format.